# How to fix layout in semantic.dashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, semantic-ui, dashboard

I am trying to create a dashboard using semantic.dashboard package in R. I have an issue with the layout of the dashboard. When I add components to the dashboard the components do not stretch to the width of the page.

I have taken the following code from examples in the semantic.dashboard github repo. It works absolutely fine when I run it. I see that there is a space between the sidebar menu and boxes in the main body. I want the components to be aligned without any space from the side bar menu. Is there any way I could achieve this?

```
library(shiny)
library(shiny.semantic)
library(semantic.dashboard)
library(plotly)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(dropdownMenuOutput("dropdown"),
              dropdownMenu(type = "notifications",
                           taskItem("Project progress...", 50.777, 
color = "red")),
              dropdownMenu(icon = uiicon("red warning sign"),
                           notificationItem("This is an important 
notification!", color = "red"))),
dashboardSidebar(side = "left",
               sidebarMenu(
                 menuItem(tabName = "plot_tab", text = "My plot", 
                          icon = icon("home")),
                 menuItem(tabName = "table_tab", text = "My table", 
                          icon = icon("smile")))),
dashboardBody(
       tabItems(
          tabItem(tabName = "plot_tab",
          fluidRow(
            valueBox("Unread Mail", 44, icon("mail"), color = 
                     "blue", width = 5)),
          fluidRow(
            box(title = "Sample box", color = "blue", width = 11,
                selectInput(inputId = "variable1", choices = 
                            names(mtcars),
                            label = "Select first variable", 
                            selected = "mpg"),
                selectInput(inputId =  "variable2", choices = 
                            names(mtcars),
                            label = "Select second variable", 
                            selected = "cyl"),
                plotlyOutput("mtcars_plot")),

            tabBox(title = "Sample box", color = "blue", width = 5,
                   collapsible = FALSE,
                   tabs = list(
                     list(menu = "First Tab", content = "Some 
                          text..."),
                     list(menu = "Second Tab", content = 
                          plotlyOutput("mtcars_plot2"))
                         )))),
            tabItem(tabName = "table_tab",
                     fluidRow(
                              valueBox("Unread Mail", 144, 
                                       icon("mail"),
                                       color = "blue", width = 6, 
                                       size = "small"),
            valueBox("Spam", 20, icon("mail"), color = "red", width 
                     = 5, size = "small"),
            valueBox("Readed Mail", 666, icon("mail"), color = 
                     "green", width = 5, size = "small")
                     ),
            fluidRow(
            box(title = "Classic box", color = "blue", ribbon = 
                FALSE, title_side = "top left", width = 14,
                tags$div(
                  dataTableOutput("mtcars_table")
                  , style = paste0("color:", 
                    semantic_palette[["blue"]], ";"))
                ))))
         ), theme = "darkly"
     )

server <- function(input, output) {

output$mtcars_plot <- renderPlotly(
                      plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~ mtcars[ , 
                               input$variable1],
                               y = ~ mtcars[ ,input$variable2],
                                type = "scatter", mode ="markers")
  )
output$mtcars_plot2 <- renderPlotly(
                       plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~ mtcars[ , 
                               input$variable1],
                               y = ~ mtcars[ ,input$variable2],
                               type = "scatter", mode ="markers"))

output$mtcars_table <- renderDataTable(mtcars, options = 
                                      list(dom ='t'))

output$dropdown <- renderDropdownMenu({
dropdownMenu(messageItem("User", "Test message", color = "teal", 
style = "min-width: 200px"),
             messageItem("Users", "Test message", color = "teal", 
icon = "users"),
             messageItem("See this", "Another test", icon = 
"warning", color = "red"))
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am encountering a similar issue, when I run the "Full Code" segment at https://appsilon.com/create-outstanding-dashboards-with-the-new-semantic-dashboard-package/ it does not look the same for me. Increased padding and the colors do not match.